# HTML accept-charset for form fields

Tags: html, forms

I wondered if it were possible for a form field to accept characters with accents for example `Ś` or `ý` 
and then when submitted for them to be shown as the raw letter (`Ś` or `ý`) rather than "random symbols"*, such as percents.*.

Is this possible?

Comment: This works normally. You'll have to supply all the details of what you are doing for anyone to explain why it isn't working for you.

Comment: http://2v2.lolnode.com/register.php?type=999 - take a look

Answer (score 0):

Are you already tried using of the attribute accept-charset?

[Html form accept-charset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp)

Comment: `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` only works for characters like the `Ś` not the `ý`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use both character which I asked about, `ISO-8859-8` is needed.